# Segmentation fault on simple Bison script

Tags: c++, c, bison, yacc, lex

OK, I'm doing a few experiments with Lex/Bison(Yacc), and given that my C skills are rather rusty (I've once created compilers and stuff with all these tools and now I'm lost in the first few lines... :-S), I need your help.

**This is what my Parser looks like :**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
} 

main()
{
    yyparse();
} 

%}

%union 
{
    char* str;
}

%token <str> WHAT IS FIND GET SHOW WITH POSS OF NUMBER WORD

%type <str> statement
%start statements
%%

statement
    : GET { printf("get\n"); }
    | SHOW  { printf("%s\n",$1); }
    | OF { printf("of\n"); }
    ;

statements
    : statement
    | statements statement
    ;
```

**The Issue :**

So, basically, whenever the parser comes across a "get", it prints "get". And so on.

However, when trying to print "show" (using the `$1` specifier) it gives out a `segmentation fault` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's the answer (Can somebody tell me what it is that I always come up with the solution once I've already published a question here in SO? lol!)

The problem was *not* with the parser itself, but actually with the Lexer.

The thing is : when you tell it to `{ printf("%s\n",$1); }`, we actually tell it to print `yylval` (which is by default an `int`, not a string).

So, the trick is to convert the appropriate tokens into strings.

Here's my (updated) Lexer file :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"

void toStr();
%}

DIGIT               [0-9]
LETTER              [a-zA-Z]
LETTER_OR_SPACE     [a-zA-Z ]

%%

find    { toStr(); return FIND; }
get     { toStr(); return GET; }
show    { toStr(); return SHOW; }

{DIGIT}+(\.{DIGIT}+)?   { toStr(); return NUMBER; }
{LETTER}+               { toStr(); return WORD; }
\n                      /* ignore end of line */;
[ \t]+                  /* ignore whitespace */;
%%

void toStr()
{
    yylval.str=strdup(yytext);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lex returns a number representing the token, you need to access yytext to get the text of what is parsed.

something like

```
statement               : GET { printf("get\n"); }
                        | SHOW  { printf("%s\n",yytext); }
                        | OF { printf("of\n"); }
                        ;
```

to propogate the text of terminals, I go ahead associate a nonterminal with a terminal and pass back the char* and start building the parse tree for example.  Note I've left out the type decl and the implementation of create_sww_ASTNode(char*,char*,char*); However, importantly not all nonterminals will return the same type, for number is an integer, word return char* sww return astNode (or whatever generic abstract syntax tree structure you come up with).  Usually beyond the nonterminal representing terminals, it's all AST stuff.

```
sww                     : show word word
                        {
                           $$ = create_sww_ASTNode($1,$2,$3);
                        }
                        ;

word                    : WORD
                        { 
                          $$ = malloc(strlen(yytext) + 1);
                          strcpy($$,yytext);
                        }
                        ;

show                    : SHOW
                        { 
                          $$ = malloc(strlen(yytext) + 1);
                          strcpy($$,yytext);
                        }
                        ;

number                  : NUMBER
                        { 
                           $$ = atoi(yytext);
                        }
                        ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! (I'm actually writing an answer myself, at this very moment) WHat if there are more than one tokens and need - let's say the 2nd one? Like : `SHOW WORD WORD { printf("%s\n",$2);`

Comment: I've posted my approach and waiting for yours. Let's see what we can get out of it! Thanks again, my friend! ;-)

Comment: -1 You can never reliably access `yytext` directly in the parser, as the parser may read ahead a token, so you don't know which token you'll get, or what state the buffer will be in.  Instead, you need to copy the data out of `yytext` in the *lexer* code, storing it into `yylval` for the parser to access.

Comment: Never?  I wonder.  Maybe this works so long as you never access yytext in the parser except when it equates to exactly 1 token.  After all the production nonterm ::== terminal will always be a reduce.

Comment: @waTeim: Never reliably.  The problem is that using `yytext` like this can appear to work at first, but then an apparently unrelated change in another part of the grammar can make it break.  While the `nonterm: terminal` production will reduce, it's not clear exactly WHEN -- whether a lookahead will be involved or not.  In your example here, there's no lookahead, so it appears to work, but a minor change could change that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your lexer code, but the problem is probably that you never set `yylval` to anything, so when you access `$1` in the parser, it contains garbage and you get a crash.  Your lexer actions need to set `yylval.str` to something so it will be valid:

```
"show"   { yylval.str = "SHOW"; return SHOW }
[a-z]+   { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return WORD; }
```

Comment: Please have a look at my own answer. And yep, the trick was something  along the lines of your approach... :)